# How to use xkbprint?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout

There are no examples in the manual and every file I've tried needs some *geometry*.

```
$ xkbcomp /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ua tmp/ua.xkm

$ xkbprint tmp/ua.xkm
Cannot open "tmp/ua.xkm" to read geometry

$ xkbprint /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ua
Error: Couldn't read geometry from XKM file "/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ua"
Exiting
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To build on [gioele's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/482206/119882), to preview custom keyboard layout, you can also use `xkbcomp` like this:

```
setxkbmap ua -print | xkbcomp - - | xkbprint - - | ps2pdf - > ua.pdf
```

`ua` being the desired keyboard layout.

Inspect `setxkbmap -print` — it provides `xkbcomp` with geometry, symbols, keycodes, ...

Comment: Great trick with `setxkbmap -layout se -variant dvorak | xkbcomp - - | `.  Another trick is to use `localectl list-x11-keymap-layouts` and  `localectl list-x11-keymap-variants se` to see which country layout and variants there are that can be used instead of `au`, like `se(dvorak)`.  Like `setxkbmap -layout se -variant 'dvorak'  -print | xkbcomp - - | xkbprint -lg1 -color - - | ps2pdf - > se.pdf`.

Answer (score 7):

```
The source can be ... or an X display specification.
```

`xkbprint :0 -o xkbprint_output.ps`

Comment: for viewing directly in bash: `zathura <(xkbprint :0 -o - | ps2pdf -)`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your are compiling with `xkbcomp` a symbol table, not a geometry.

Try

```
$ xkbcomp /usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/ua - tmp/ua.xkm
$ xkbprint -color tmp/ua.xkm
```

or (without temp files and with a PDF output):

```
$ xkbcomp /usr/share/X11/xkb/geometry/ua - | xkbprint -color -o - - | ps2pdf - > ua.pdf
```